# How Set Model Data Before TableView Reload

Tags: ios, swift, closures, tableview, codable

TableView reloads before set model data(topRatedModel) so models remains nil. I used main tread but it didn't work. How can i fix this ? You can check my code on: https://github.com/melisaozturk/MVVM
(main branch is up to date)

```
    class MovieViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let viewModel = MovieViewModel()
    var topRatedModel: MovieTopRatedModel!
    var nowPlayingModel: MovieNowPlayingModel!
    var popularModel: MoviePopularModel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableRegister()
        self.viewModel.getTopRatedData(completion: { [weak self] response in
            if let _ = self {return}
            self!.topRatedModel = response
        }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
             if let _ = self {return}
        })
        
        
        self.viewModel.getNowPlayingData(completion: { [weak self] response in
            if let _ = self {return}
            self!.nowPlayingModel = response
        }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
            if let _ = self {return}
        })
        
        self.viewModel.getPopularData(completion: { [weak self] response in
            if let _ = self {return}
            self!.popularModel = response
        }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
            if let _ = self {return}
        })
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
       
    }

     private func tableRegister() {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MovieCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MovieCell")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload the table view once all of the data has finished loading.  Your code now reloads the table view while those network operations are still running.

Now, you have three network operations and you don't want to reload until they are all complete and you don't know in which order they are going to complete.

You can use a [`DispatchGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) to help you here.

Using `notify` on a `DispatchGroup` you can execute some code when the dispatch group becomes empty.

You also have some bugs with your handling of the `weak self` - Your code will return if self isn't nil.  You want the opposite.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.tableRegister()

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        self.viewModel.getTopRatedData(completion: { [weak self] response in
            if let self = self else {
                self.topRatedModel = response               
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
             dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
        
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        self.viewModel.getNowPlayingData(completion: { [weak self] response in
            if let self = self {
                self.nowPlayingModel = response
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
        
        self.viewModel.getPopularData(completion: { [weak self] response in
            if let self = self {
                self.popularModel = response
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
        
        dispatchGroup.notify {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
       
    }
```

From a style point of view, I would use a `Result` type or at least a closure that accepts a `(Response?,Error?)` rather than having two closures.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I made a mistake suggesting changing the async for sync. This is wrong since it could cause the main thread to get blocked as @Paulw11 pointed out.

A solution I can think of is using DispatchGroups or a dispatch semaphore. I am personally more comfortable with DispatchGroups so I'll leave you some pseudo-code on how you might want to implement it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.tableRegister()

    let dispatcher = DispatchGroup()

    //for every function that you want to wait for you make an dispatcher.enter()
    dispatcher.enter()
    self.viewModel.getTopRatedData(completion: { [weak self] response in
        if let _ = self {return}
        self!.topRatedModel = response
    }, completionHandler: { [weak self] error in
         if let _ = self {
             // when each of the functions has finished running you can write a dispatcher.leave()
             dispatcher.leave()
             return
         }
    })
    
    // This code will wait for all dispatcher.leaves() to run in order to execute the following code.
    dispatcher.notify(.main){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
   
}
```

I hope I was able to help a little. If you need more clarification with anything I'll be glad to help.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use `sync()` - You risk blocking the main thread.  It also won't work since there is no sychronisation with the async network tasks

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know that. I'll try to be more aware for future responses and will edit this one. Also I meant I was NOT super sure about it instead of saying I was, sorry.